# How to inherit from a class with __init__ and take input parms

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two classes as follows:

```
class Buttons():
  def __init__(self, dDict):  
    self.TCT = Tool()
    self.dDict = dDict

  def btnName(self):
    # I will use both self.TCT and self.dDict here
    a = self.dDict['setup']

class Switch(Buttons):
  def __init__(self):
    self.TCT =Tool()
```

I need to instantiate `Switch` class, but I need to provide `dDict` so that `Buttons` class will have the data it is looking for. What is the right way to instantiate the class `Switch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit the `__init__` from your parent class as follows:

```
class Switch(Buttons):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Followed by init code that is used by Switch
```

This also means that you don't need to repeat the `self.TCT =Tool()` in your new `__init__`.

You can then safely call

```
switch = Switch(mydict)
```

Comment: Given this is Python 3, you'd omit the arguments to `super()`, making it just `super().__init__(*args)` (and you might want to receive and pass along `**kwargs` to allow passing arguments by keyword too).

Comment: What would be the case if my Switch class took input parm with a default value? How do I change your code for that?

Comment: I'd recommend to ask a new question for that, makes it easier to handle!

Comment: I just posted it here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721803/how-to-inherit-from-a-class-with-init-and-take-multiple-input-parms-with-def